# Change text within Label to option from selection menu

Tags: javascript, html, select, drop-down-menu, label

This my custom select menu:

```
<select name="bankSelect" id="bankSelect" onchange="dispchange(this.form.bankSelect)">
    <option>EQUIFAX</option>
    <option value = 5 >EQUIFAX</option>
    <option value = 6>TRANSUNION</option>
    <option value = 7>EXPERIAN</option>
    <option value = 8>BANK OF AMERICA</option>
    <option value = 9>WELLS FARGO</option>
    <option value = 10>CITIBANK</option>
    <option value = 11>JPMORGAN</option>
    <option value = 12>NAVIENT</option>
    <option value = 13>CAPITAL ONE</option>
    <option value = 14>U.S BANCORP</option>
</select>
```

This is my label:

```
<div class="info">
   <label>Bank: </label>
   <label id="bank">EQUIFAX</label><br>
</div>
```

I need to change the text within label with the ID='bank to the option i select from the menu i above.

So if i pick the option with value 9, then my label should change the text it's displaying by defualt,'EQUIFAX' to then display 'WELLS FARGO'.

This is what I've tried in my java-script based on googling similar questions:

```
function dispchange(bankSelect) {
    var bsel_index = bankSelect.selectedIndex;
    var bselin = bankSelect.options[bsel_index].value;
    if(bselin == '6')
      document.getElementById("bank").innerHTML = 'Transunion';
    else if(opcao == '1')
      document.getElementById('complemento').innerHTML = 'Titulo';
 }
```

It does nothing. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way / another way to change the label? Can I use something other than a label to display my choice from the selection menu? If so, how do I ensure is always displays the choice currently selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function dispchange(bankSelect) {
  console.log(document.getElementById("bankSelect").value)
  document.getElementById('bank').innerHTML = document.getElementById("bankSelect").value;
    

 }
```

```html
<select name="bankSelect" id="bankSelect" onchange="dispchange()">
    <option value="EQUIFAX">EQUIFAX</option>
    <option value="TRANSUNION">TRANSUNION</option>
    <option value ="EXPERIAN">EXPERIAN</option>
    <option value= "BANK OF AMERICA">BANK OF AMERICA</option>
    <option value ="WELLS FARGO">WELLS FARGO</option>
</select>

<div class="info">
   <label>Bank: </label>
   <label id="bank">EQUIFAX</label><br>
</div>
```

If you can change the value of the options from number to the Bank name then the following code is going to work as you need.
Otherwise, you have to create an array or object with the numbers and Bank names.
Is the above code work for you?

Comment: Actually I take that back, I made a typo. This works perfectly! Thank you :)

Comment: You are welcome :) Happy to hear that :)
Oh yes @Re Undo is correct. I forgot the option.text code actually.

Answer (score 2):

use `option.text` instead of `option.value`:

```js
function dispchange() {
    var el = document.getElementById('bankSelect');
    document.getElementById('bank').innerHTML = el.options[el.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

```html
<select name="bankSelect" id="bankSelect" onchange="dispchange()">
    <option>EQUIFAX</option>
    <option value="5">EQUIFAX</option>
    <option value="6">TRANSUNION</option>
    <option value="7">EXPERIAN</option>
    <option value="8">BANK OF AMERICA</option>
    <option value="9">WELLS FARGO</option>
    <option value="10">CITIBANK</option>
    <option value="11">JPMORGAN</option>
    <option value="12">NAVIENT</option>
    <option value="13">CAPITAL ONE</option>
    <option value="14">U.S BANCORP</option>
</select>
<div class="info">
   <label>Bank: </label>
   <label id="bank">EQUIFAX</label><br>
</div>
```

Comment: I only saw this after accepting the answer above, but in case anyone else is looking at this, i tried this on a copy of my file and its works perfectly as well.